# Upload a file via form submit programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` library to upload a file into the sharepoint website. There is a url that looks like:
https://a.sharepoint.com/b/c/d/FormName.aspx. It is accessible via browser, I can upload files via browser too.

If I navigate to https://a.sharepoint.com/b/c/ I get redirected to https://a.sharepoint.com/b/c/d/FormName.aspx so it looks like the default form, assigned to the website.

In case I navigate to https://a.sharepoint.com/b, it says I lack permissions to access that website.

I am creating a context like: `ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(WebsiteURL)`. In case I use https://a.sharepoint.com as a url, I can connect to that site, but I cant see the destination folder (`b`) among sharepoint folders and lists. It says directory was not found when I try accessing it directly. 
So, my question is: how do I upload a file/submit that form programatically in case I don't have access to the parent website?

Comment: That URL points to a *form*, not a document library. It's useless. You need the name of the document library instead and use ti with eg `List[]` to access the doc library.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to get one from that website?